# How do I get notification when my issued was closed on github?

Tags: github

When my issued is closed I don't get email notification. I google it but I can't find a way to get notification. Currently I have check to **Recent activity** at my github login page regularly and check if my issue was disappeared or not. If it was disappeared I know it was closed.

So is there any way, or any setting I miss, to let me get the notification for that ?

Comment: It would show up on your [notifications tab](https://github.com/notifications) when modified.

Comment: I knew that but when I am watching several projects I will get many messages so it is not easy to see my issue. Actually I kinda feel github is not able to do that currently but I am also surprised github lacks such function.

Comment: You could bookmark a custom issues search. For example, closed issues created by you, sorted by most recent updated, created this year (`is:closed is:issue author:@me sort:updated-desc created:>2024-01-01`): https://github.com/issues?q=is%3Aclosed+is%3Aissue+author%3A%40me+sort%3Aupdated-desc+created%3A%3E2024-01-01

Comment: But do you see all the methods are indirect. I just want a notification when my issue is closed. How hard is that ?!

Comment: You could write a GitHub Actions workflow that checks for you and notifies you.

Comment: Thanks, I asked @ https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions to see if I can get an answer there.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Hi, I have verified the answer I got from https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/113109

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/113109. I did not get any email notification because I didn't turn it on (the default setting)

[image: github notification]

As I said in the comment I knew I can check my [notifications tab](https://github.com/notifications) but when I am watching several projects I will get many messages and it is not easy to see my own issue. So I prefer to get an email notification when my issue is closed.